# Which is the synthesized digital circuit for this [verilog] mux with an uncompleted sensibility list?

Tags: verilog, circuit

Which is the synthesized **not optimized** digital circuit for the following code:

a, b and c are 1 bit long.
sel has 2 bits.

```
always@(a, b, sel)
case(sel)
    begin
    2'b00: a;
    2'b01: b;
    2'b10: c;
    default: 0;
    end
endcase
```

If i am not mistaken we would have a mux with three inputs and two selection bits.

As selection bits we have sel[0] and sel[1].
As inputs we have a, b and a latch.
The latch will have as input c and something else. I dont know what else has to enter the latch.

This question is just educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most synthesizers do not consider the sensitivity list unless it is for synchronous logic. The latching behavior you would see in simulation will not happen post-synthesis. The major reason `@*` was added in IEEE1364-2001 prevent accidental omissions from sensitivity list.

If you truly want to output a latched version of `c`, then you need to create the latch before the mux:

```
always @*
  if (lat_en) c_latch <= c;
always @*
  case(sel)
    2'b00: a;
    2'b01: b;
    2'b10: c_latch;
    default: 0;
  endcase
```

Level-sensitive latches are not common on FPGAs. The are used sparingly on ASICs due to timing concerns. Edge-sensitive flip-flops are generally preferred:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  if (update) c_ff <= c;
always @*
  case(sel)
    2'b00: a;
    2'b01: b;
    2'b10: c_ff;
    default: 0;
  endcase
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not synthesize into digital logic. The enable signal for the latch on c would have to be "when any of the 4 bits {a,b,sel} change, and then close it before c changes again".

Comment: I know that but i dont know how to build the schematic of a circuit that does it.

Comment: It’s not possible in the digital domain

Comment: from my experience, this might be synthesized to a normal mux. But it will not simulate like that at all. So, if synthesized, it will cause sim/synth mismatch. always use `always @*`